# How to view all posts of current day as default in admin

Tags: wp-query, wp-admin

I want to to show all posts of the current date by default (without clicking the filter button) in WordPress admin posts list screen.

I have used this code in `functions.php` and it works almost. The problem is when I want to view the other posts, except current date, then it will show only the posts of today's date. I'm not able to view the other posts by using this code.

```
function add_post_format_filter_to_posts( $query ) {
    global $post_type, $pagenow;
    // if we are currently on the edit screen of the post type listings
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'shop_order' ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            $query->set( 'date_query', array( array(
                'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                'after' => '1 days ago',
            ) ) );
            return;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_post_format_filter_to_posts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this modification to your code snippet:

```
function add_post_format_filter_to_posts( $query ) {

    global $post_type, $pagenow;

    // if we are currently on the edit screen of the post type listings
    if (    is_admin() 
         && $pagenow   == 'edit.php' 
         && $post_type == 'shop_order'
         && ! filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'filter_action' ) // <-- We add this check
         && ! filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'post_status'   ) // <-- and this one
    )
    {
        $query->set( 'date_query', 
            array( 
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                    'after'  => '1 days ago',
                ) 
            ) 
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_post_format_filter_to_posts' );
```

where we only do the query filtering when the  GET parameters `filter_action` and `post_status` aren't set.